# VB timestamp data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have `timestamp` type data in [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server). I wonder what should be related data type in [vb](/questions/tagged/vb)?

Should it be `string`,`date`,`Byte` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) `TIMESTAMP` is not a `DATE` data type. It is used for row versioning and usually referred to as `ROWVERSION` [Documenation here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)

with that being said, [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) treats it as binary. So I'm not sure what value it will give you in application, but if you needed to convert it to VB the closest you can get is making it a string. [VB data types documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)

here is example of `TIMESTAMP` from [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012)

```
0x000000002AB82831
0x000000002AB8280D
0x000000002AB827C4
0x000000002AB82710
0x000000002AB82758
0x000000002AB82759
0x000000002AB82832
0x000000002AB8277C
```